# SVG icons in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have to move an SVG icon from a regular website to a ReactJS website. The SVG has to be modified a little to make it compatible with JSX, so I've removed all the ':'s and replaced them with camel case attribute names for JSX compatibility. The only issue is the d attribute.

The SVG now looks like:

```
<svg id="Logo" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 900 800" enable-background="new 0 0 1024 1024" xmlSpace="preserve">
    <g id="Layer_1"></g>
    <g id="Logo">
        <g>
            <g id="Fish">
                <g>
                    <path style={{fill:"#8DC046"}} d="M430.249,525.415c0,64.563-58.349,136.165-58.349,136.165l0.434,0.435l214.046-136.867L374.238,388.279
                        l-0.594,0.596C373.644,388.875,430.249,458.241,430.249,525.415z"></path>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <path style={{fill="#B8CD43"}} d="M586.381,525.147L374.238,388.279l-0.594,0.596c0,0,56.605,69.366,56.605,136.54L586.381,525.147z"></path>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <path style={{fill="#15AADB"}} d="M430.249,253.264c0,64.145-56.444,136.163-56.444,136.163l0.433,0.435l212.143-136.868L372.334,116.125
                        l-0.595,0.598C371.739,116.723,430.249,188.18,430.249,253.264z"></path>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <path style={{fill="#4AC5ED"}} d="M586.381,252.994L372.334,116.125l-0.595,0.598c0,0,58.51,71.457,58.51,136.541L586.381,252.994z"></path>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <path style={{fill="#F88F2D"}} d="M596.473,389.394c0,216.894-135.035,388.081-135.035,388.081l0.789,0.795L889.707,388.9L462.227-0.467
                        l-1.095,1.097C461.132,0.629,596.473,177.202,596.473,389.394z"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

This gives me the following error:

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (90:58)

This makes sense, but in the d attributes in my case there are parts like `M596.473,389.394c0`. As you can imagine, the letter `c` between the 4 and 0 cause issues as the letter is not an integer.

How can I make this SVG work without using a library or something else? I just want to convert this SVG to valid JSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React does not play nice with SVG yet. If your svg is static I personally find it much easier to do it this way:

```
var img = `<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 252.5 148.7" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <polygon points="252.5,0 252.5,52.6"/>
</g>
</svg>`
```

In string you can put your svg exactly how you read it from file/DB without any extra conversions.

And then later use it in render like this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: img}}/>
```

Comment: This is good. It may not be best practise, but I only need SVG to render a simple logo, nothing more. So this is sufficient, thank you.

Comment: Be really really careful with dangerouslySetInnerHTML lest you introduce XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, definitely. In the React docs there's a piece of code that allows you to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML while also making sure there are no XSS issues, so that's been covered. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change `style={{fill="#B8CD43"}}` to `style={{fill: "#B8CD43"}}` every place, it will work.

There is no need of dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Here is the working [Demo](https://codepen.io/madhurgarg71/pen/MvGGpq)

Comment: Nice catch, and it does compile, but doesn't even include the SVG tag in the compiled HTML

Comment: You mean to say in the compiled HTML, you're not able to see the SVG?

Comment: Yeah the problem isn't in the style property at all (although the syntax was wrong like you saw). It just wasn't related to the issue. dangerouslySetInnerHTML helped resolve the issue. Thanks

Comment: @erol_smsr I tried in my react app and it's rendering perfectly.

Comment: @erol_smsr I added the demo.

Comment: Also if you want to preserve the rule: `enable-background="new 0 0 1024 1024"` should be renamed to `enableBackground="new 0 0 1024 1024"`.

Comment: @madhurgarg I'm working within an internal company framework, so it's not a pure React environment (tons of other stuff and code), so I think that's the reason I have to use the dangerous function (which I confirmed with my coworkers). I will use your tips for other React projects of course, so thank you very much. I can't accept your answer though, as it doesn't help in this case. It's worth an upvote though ;)

Comment: @erol_smsr Ohh, cool. Guys like you maintaining the quality of stackoverflow. Thanks for upvoting and being nice.